# Find a sequence of character in a String

Tags: java

I need to find a sequence of characters (in this case ffg) in a String, and when find the sequence return the character that comes before and after.

I manage to find this way using match.find(), but it return the position and I need the character that is stored there.

this output is :

```
16 ffg 20
34 ffg 38
47 ffg 51
60 ffg 64
```

and I need:

```
g ffg k
d ffg k
```

Code follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testes {

public static void main(String[]args){

        String text = "aaddbsanklfafjdkgffgkakfjkldsjlkfjdffgkaskdlfkdkffgasjdaeflkaffgaff";

        String wordToFind = "ffg";


        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        while (match.find()) {

             System.out.print(match.start() - 1);
             System.out.print(" " + wordToFind + " ");
             System.out.println(match.end());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `String.charAt(match.start() - 1)`?

Comment: So what's the problem with the code you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

.start() and .end() return offsets in the original string. If you want to do something will those offsets then you probably want to use .substring (on your original string).

Answer (score 1):

Output

```
g ffg k
d ffg k
k ffg a
a ffg a
```

Code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "aaddbsanklfafjdkgffgkakfjkldsjlkfjdffgkaskdlfkdkffgasjdaeflkaffgaff";

        String wordToFind = "ffg";

        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        while (match.find()) {
            System.out.print(text.charAt(match.start() - 1));
            System.out.print(" " + wordToFind + " ");
            System.out.println(text.charAt(match.end()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im new with java, just start 2 weeks ago.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to find `"ffg"` in the string `"aaddbsanklfafjdkgffgkakfjkldsjlkfjdffgkaskdlfkdkffgasjdaeflkaffgaff"`.

The first thing to do would be to create `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects that we will be using.

```
Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
Matcher match = word.matcher(text);
```

You mostly had everything you needed, apart from the call to get the character at the required index. The following code snippet yields the required output.

**Output**

```
g ffg k                                                                                                                                       
d ffg k                                                                                                                                       
k ffg a                                                                                                                                       
a ffg a
```

This is the code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "aaddbsanklfafjdkgffgkakfjkldsjlkfjdffgkaskdlfkdkffgasjdaeflkaffgaff";

    String wordToFind = "ffg";

    Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
    Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

    // keep searching while there are instances 
    // of `wordToFind` in the string
    while (match.find()) {
        // index before the wordToFind starts
        int startIndx = match.start() - 1;
        System.out.print(text.charAt(startIndx));

        System.out.print(" ");

        // print word
        System.out.print(wordToFind);

        System.out.print(" ");

        // index where wordToFind ends
        int endIndx = match.end();
        System.out.println(text.charAt(endIndx));

    }    
}
```